# Rails attr_accessor defined attributes outside of strong params hash in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, parameters, strong-parameters

Consider the following `User` model

*schema:*

```
create_table "users", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "fname"
    t.string "lname"
end
```

*Model:*

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :email # no column in database
end
```

*Controller:*

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:fname, :lname, :email)
end
```

I'm writing an API to which I'm sending a POST request to the `users` endpoint with the following keys/values:

```
{
    "fname": "John",
    "lname": "Doe",
    "email": "email@email.com",
}
```

I would expect `params[:user]` to include the key `:email` as even though it is not a database column, it is defined as an attribute via the `attr_accessor` in the model.

However, the `:email` key is not nested within `params[:user]`, and has to be accessed at the params level `params[:email]`.

```
# POST /users { "fname": "John", "lname": "Doe", "email": "email@email.com" }
Processing by UsersController#create as JSON

Parameters: {"user"=>{"fname"=>John, "lname"=>"Doe"}, "email"=>"email@email.com"}
```

I believe `ActionController#params_wrapper` has something to do with this, but I don't understand the code enough to make it wrap `attr_accessor` defined attributes inside the  `user` hash.

I need the `:email` key nested within `params[:user]`. Is there a way around this?

Comment: It is truly bizzare - how did you inspect parameters? Is it just `puts params` in the controller? It is very unlikely rails is modifying oncoming params - it does not refer to a model at all at this stage and it happens even before the controller is initialized. So most likely you're not sending the request the way you think you do

Comment: Actually I believe it has something to do with it. I just found this https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26708

Comment: When you expect those attributes to be nested under `:user` in the `strong_params` why don't you send them nested in your request? Depending on `params_wrapper` seems to be a bad idea. And I actually always disable it because it caused issues for me in the past.

Comment: @pinkfloyd90: yeah, apologies, my bad. I didn't notice you posted the actual payload you send.

Comment: @spickermann: same, no params_wrapper in api endpoints for me.

Comment: Since it's an API endpoint, clients are already familiar with sending the attributes key/values at the root level without specifiying that they are for the `user` model. `{k/v}` instead of `{ user: {k/v} }`

Comment: @pinkfloyd90: even if so, why use logic meant to handle forms from the rails form builder? `params.permit(:fname, :lname, :email)` or even `params.to_h.slice(:fname, :lname, :email)`?

Answer (score 2):

> I believe ActionController#params_wrapper has something to do with this

Good hunch. However, you were too quick to jump into the code. Should have read the docs first :)

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html

> You can also specify the key in which the parameters should be wrapped to, and also the list of attributes it should wrap by using either :include or :exclude options like this:
>
> ```
> class UsersController < ApplicationController
>    wrap_parameters :person, include: [:username, :password]
> end
> ```
>
> On Active Record models with no :include or :exclude option set, it will only wrap the parameters returned by the class method `attribute_names`.

Comment: Thanks. I read that but declaring `wrap_parameters :user, include: [:email]` makes the `:email` the  only wrapped parameter and discards the rest. I can't find a way to make it wrap model attributes by default + whatever is defined in the `attr_accessor`

Comment: @pinkfloyd90 `wrap_parameters :user, include: attribute_names + [:email]`? Or you could try overriding `attribute_names`, but this sounds like it can backfire easily.